# Firestore enum compatibility

Tags: c#, google-cloud-firestore

I am using cloud firestore as db. Problem is that firestore seems to do not support enums. I want to store class which constains dictionaries with enum as key. Is there any way how to overcome this? Only solution that I found so far is convert my class to json object and than store it to db, but I dont like because of performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Your only real option here is the convert the enum into a unique string, which is usually the same name as the enum itself.  Before you cite "performance reasons", you should actually benchmark your solution and see if it's as bad as you think (it's probably not).